# squared-off line plot matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

How do I generate a line graph in Matplotlib where lines connecting the data points are only vertical and horizontal, not diagonal, giving a "blocky" look?

Note that this is sometimes called *zero order extrapolation*.

## MWE

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 3, 5, 7]
y = [2, 0, 4, 1]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

This gives:

[image: diagonal graph]

and I want:

[image: perpendicular graph]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `plt.step`. Here are [some examples.](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html)